# django add amp; to context value , how to solve that ,

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I pass url from view by context like this :

```
context = {"url":"https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/logatta-space/organization_survey/static/img/page1-d.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=DO00GN8LVUJB9VNAQL69&Signature=EM6bumz7gPzaPBPqHHdGfqBMVWk%3D&Expires=1670256832"}     
 return render(request, 'index1.html', context)
```

when i recive the same url like this from chrome inspect:

```
 .start-template {
    background-image:url(https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/logatta-space/organization_survey/static/img/page1-d.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=DO00GN8LVUJB9VNAQL69&amp;Signature=EM6bumz7gPzaPBPqHHdGfqBMVWk%3D&amp;Expires=1670256832);
    }
```

the template add **amp;**  to the url inside the template and this casess some problems

and this is my html code :

```
        background-image:url({{url}});
```

my question:
how to pass url as is ,without add amp; in middel of my url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid escaping you can use [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-safe) template tag

```
url({{ url | safe }})
```

However your case perhaps needs further refactoring:

think of using [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATIC_URL) to parameterise root url for such files and joining it with specific file path inside some function which would build full static file url. If built-in function [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urls/#static) does not suffice your needs.